# r why is package R.oo being called and generating errors

Tags: r

To the best of my knowledge I had never installed `R.oo` before this problem started. Since I installed R version 3.6 I have found at least a couple of packages that fail when I try to load them with `library()`. I had installed R.oo on my system (Rstudio, Macbook Pro) but then deleted it to see what difference that would make. The most recent example is

```
library(qrcode)
```

Without R.oo installed, I get the following error message

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘qrcode’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘R.oo’
```

After installing R.oo, `library(qrcode)` returns

```
Registered S3 method overwritten by 'R.oo':
  method        from       
  throw.default R.methodsS3
```

Next I did library(R.oo) which loaded successfully and returned

```
Loading required package: R.methodsS3
R.methodsS3 v1.7.1 (2016-02-15) successfully loaded. See ?R.methodsS3 for help.
R.oo v1.22.0 (2018-04-21) successfully loaded. See ?R.oo for help.
```

Hmm. I didn't have R.methodsS3 installed so went ahead and did that and then retried `library(qrcode)`. This time no errors.

A second package with this problem is `mailR`. The solution again seems to be to run `library(R.oo)` and `library(R.methodsS3)` and then `library(mailR)`.

While this *seems* to work (haven't tested much) it seems like quite a kludge. Are there better ways to deal with this?

Comment: When you ask for " better ways to deal with this", what exactly is the "this"? If you delete a package dependency, that will likely stop a package from working. If you try to reinstall a package, it should attempt to reinstall the dependencies assuming they are available for your version of R.

Comment: I would like to not have to explicitly add two libraries that I don't use -  R.oo and R.methodsS3.  ` tools::package_dependencies("mailR", recursive = TRUE)` returns `$mailR
 [1] "rJava"       "stringr"     "R.utils"     "R.oo"        "methods"     "utils"       "tools"      
 [8] "R.methodsS3" "glue"        "magrittr"    "stringi"     "stats" ` so something is calling R.methodsS3. Not sure what to do now.

Comment: Those packages are listed as dependencies of `mailR` so in order to use `mailR` you need to use those two packages. What exactly doesn't work if you call `library(mailR)` without calling `library()` on those two packages first? It seems unlikely you'd get the "there is no package called" if it is at least installed (doesn't have to be loaded).

Comment: The direct dependencies of mailR are rJava, stringr, and R.utils. The remaining dependencies in my list above are dependencies of the dependencies. What happens with mailR is the same as happens with qrcode - Registered S3 method overwritten (see above).

Comment: status of that issue: https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/R.utils/issues/95